# How do I display content from a wp object array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have two tables/post types. One is events and the other is programs.
In the events post type I have added a custom field for 'related programs' using the 'Advanced Custom Fields' plugin.

I want to display the post excerpt of the program on the events page.

When I call the print_r function on get_field('related_program') within my WP standard while loop, I get the following array:

*Array ( [0] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 69 [post_excerpt] => XYZ ))*

**How do I access the post_excerpt from the array?**

When I try the following

```
$relatedPrograms = get_field('related_program');

foreach($relatedPrograms as $program) {
  echo $program[0]['post_excerpt'] }
```

I get the error code:

*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post*

Comment: Update: found the answer here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146614/get-data-from-wordpress-object-array